# Local AppFabric and Local Memcache - Strictly Performance Speaking

Tags: c#, memcached, appfabric

At work we are discussing the possibility for a dedicated in-memory cache server. The two choices are Windows AppFabric Cache Server and Memcached. So I setup two tests, one for AppFabric and one for Memcache.

Memcache tests
OS/Appliance
[Memcache VMWare Appliance](http://istanbul.sourceforge.net/)
Virtualized in VMWare Workstation, Quad Core with 8gb of ram with the MemCachedDOTnet_2.0 C# API.

After I pushed a few objects into cache I started my timings and got on average.

- Put 0-1MS (accuracy was only to milliseconds)
- Get 14-15MS

AppFabric Cache Server
No VM because its all windows. Quad Core with 8gb of ram.
Same thing I pushed a few objects to cache before I started working. Local Cache option was disabled in the client settings.

- Put 0-1MS (accuracy was only to milliseconds)
- Get 0-1ms (accuracy was only to milliseconds)

Now the question is I have heard MemCached is super fast, but I assumed it to be faster then AppFabric, but not 15ms slower on Gets vs AppFabric. What is everyone else's performance for both AppFabric  and/or MemCache. I'm just looking for raw numbers of MS and object size or things I should look at to see if I can make the numbers line up more to my expectations or options to set or check on.

Comment: I've used AppFabric very successfully and found that it performs very well in high traffic scenario's with thousands of concurrent connections. That said, I too find it surprising that memcache seems to be performing so badly. I have never come accross MemCachedDOTnet_2.0 before, so maybe this could be a bottle neck as well, although my first hunch was certainly the VM.

Comment: @s1mm0t I should of though of the client that I was using. I will try and grab a few more and edit the question to list them above once I have a few more results.

Comment: josh instead of running Memcache on a VM, try running it on a *nix based machine and then run your comparison tests. Memcache was made to run primarily on *nix systems. The windows ports have got it working on a windows environment. That is not to say it performs to its best when using Windows as a host. Also if you tried out Prathul's suggestion below, could you let us know the outcome?

Comment: @user20358 with app fabric now having an end-of-life, i'm closing this questions as the software will no longer be maintained. More details here http://blogs.msdn.com/b/appfabric/archive/2015/04/02/windows-server-appfabric-1-1-ends-support-4-2-2016.aspx

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because appfabric 1.1 will no longer be supported by microsoft. This will prevent future comments. I couldn't find a right reason to close for obsolete software.

Answer (score 3):

I see that you have enabled local cache on Appfabric. When local cache is enabled, the cache client stores a reference to the object locally. This keeps the object active in the memory of the client application. When the application requests the object, the cache client first checks whether the object resides in the local cache. If so, the reference to the object is returned immediately without contacting the server. If it does not exist, the object is retrieved from the server. After objects are stored in the local cache, your application continues to use those objects until they are invalidated, regardless of whether those objects are updated by another client on the cache cluster. For this reason, it is best to use local cache for data that changes infrequently.

Since you had local cache enabled, the object was returned immediately without contacting the cluster. If your data changes frequently and you have low tolerance for stale data, you should have local cache disabled. Try the same tests on Windows Server Appfabric 1.1 with local cache disabled.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you test the windows version of memcached so that you're comparing apples with apples? When you're running one of them in a vm you'll also get the overhead of the extra OS..

Comment: 1. From the windows port of memcached "This port is not supported by the official memcached team."
2. I understand there is overhead with the extra OS, but if a put is 0-1ms and a get is 14-15ms that makes it seem the overhead might be related to the software not the VM layer.
3. At work any solution will be in a VM, so the overhead will always be present.